# QTermWidget: simulating a key press Python/C++

Tags: c++, python, qt, terminal

So I'm trying to send a simulated return key to QTermWidget in my program. I have working version of this in both Python /Qt4 and C++/Qt4. At this point I really do not care if it is written in either language now that I have a decent grasp on C++ syntax. That being said an answer for either language would be a godsend.

So far I've tried

```
   QTest.KeyClick(self.Terminal, Qt.KeyReturn, Qt.NoModifier) // syntax is python here
```

and

```
    key_press = QKeyEvent(QEvent.KeyPress, Qt.Key_Return, Qt.NoModifier)
    self.Terminal.keyPressEvent(key_press)
    key_release = QKeyEvent(QEvent.KeyRelease, Qt.Key_Return, Qt.NoModifier)
    self.Terminal.keyPressEvent(key_release)
```

and a few other that I can't fully remember now.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in C++?

```
QKeyEvent *ev = new QKeyEvent( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Return, Qt::NoModifier );
myApp->postEvent( receivingWidget, ev );
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, should be working with other widgets, too.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, Qt
from ChildWindow import ChildWindow

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, self.showChildWindow)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.resize(100, 100)

    def showChildWindow(self):
        QtGui.QApplication.sendEvent(self.textEdit, QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtGui.QKeyEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_A, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, "hello"))
        QtGui.QApplication.sendEvent(self.textEdit, QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtGui.QKeyEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```